# Loadtext for specific number of lines

Tags: python, numpy, text

I have a huge file to load so I can't open it directly. I think I have to read it in multiple parts.

For instance, in order to use lines 1 to 50, I tried with something like that, but it doesn't work:

```
import numpy as np

with open('test.txt') as f:
    lines = (line for line in f if line < 50.)
    FH = np.loadtxt(lines, delimiter=',', skiprows=1)
```

Comment: `lines = [f.readline() for _ in range(50)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3, please try this:

```
a = 0
f = open('test.txt')
while a < 50:
    a = a + 1
    print(f.readline(), end='')
else:
    f.close()
```

In Python 2, use this:

```
a = 0
f = open('test.txt')
while a < 50:
    a = a + 1
    print f.readline(),
else:
    f.close()
```

or choose this way, use `readlines()`:

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    text = f.readlines()
```

`readlines()` will create a list, and **one line is one object**. so if you want the 20 - 50 lines, you can do this:

```
for i in text[20:50]:
    print(i)
```

Comment: that works well when i begin at 0 but if i want to consider a beginning at 10 how can i do that? thanks for help

Comment: I try with print f.readline()[10:] but it plays on"horizontal data"

Comment: easiest way: use `readline()` read the first 10 lines use this solution, and don't print them. Then you can read the file consider a beginning at 10.

Comment: Sorry i have some difficulties to see :/ could you modify please the part of code?

Comment: Finished, I think that `readlines()` is the best way to do this :)

Answer (score 4):

As you are using `numpy`, you can use the [`islice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=islice#itertools.islice) function in the built in `itertools` library to load just the first 50 lines as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

with open('test.txt') as f_input:
    FH = np.loadtxt(itertools.islice(f_input, 0, 50), delimiter=',', skiprows=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting `Numpy 1.16`, [`np.loadtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html?highlight=loadtxt#numpy-loadtxt) takes an optional parameter `max_rows` which limits the number of lines to read:

```
import numpy as np

np.loadtxt('file.txt', max_rows=50, delimiter=',', skiprows=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I use function to read arbitrary first, last N-lines from file:

```
def read_first_last_N_lines_from_file(in_file,N,last=False):
    with open(in_file) as myfile:
        if last:
            return [x.strip() for x in list(myfile)][-N:]
        return [next(myfile).strip() for x in range(N)]
```