# Python - Loadtext with specific lines for huge file

Tags: python, text, readline

I have to get specific lines in a huge text file. Until now i try as below. My aim is to extract columns for a specific iteration, here each 500 lines. But by proceeding with the "readlines", sometimes i get some crashes because of the size of the file (until 4Gb).
So i would like to find an other way in order to avoid problems...

```
with open('/test.txt') as f:
    text = f.readlines()


A = ""    
for i in text[3000:3500]:
  A+=i

B=A.splitlines()
listed = []
for i in range(len(B)):
  C=B[i][3:47].split(" ")

  while True:
    try:
      C.remove("")
    except ValueError:
      break
  listed.append(C)

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#print listed
x = np.array(listed, dtype=float)
y = x.astype(np.float)

plt.plot(y[:,1]);plt.ylim(0,5);plt.show()
```

This post follows a former [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32559304/python-loadtext-for-specific-number-of-lines).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to get the lines 3000 to 3500. You can do this like such:

```
import itertools
with open('test.txt') as f:
    lines = list(itertools.islice(f, 3000, 3500))
```

Comment: Yep i want these lines without to open all file! But how i can join your code to mine? I dont understand the output... sorry

Comment: @user3601754 Replace `text[3000:3500]` with `lines` and put my code at the top instead of your `with` block.

Comment: Ok but i get "I/O operation on closed file"

Comment: Thanks a lot it s exactly what i expected :)